# How to select one column so that todays total shows up as yesterdays

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement that pulls the following information:

```
Site  Date  Scheduled  Arrived yesterday
A      3/26   45         51
A      3/25   40         37
A      3/24   60         55
```

I need the results to look like this:

```
Site  Date  Scheduled  Arrived yesterday
A      3/26  45          NULL
A      3/25  40          51
A      3/24  60          37
```

I am fairly new to sql and am not sure how to select the data to make the values in the arrived yesterday column shift to the previous day without affecting the other columns. I have tried things like dateadd, but Im not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       lead(arrived_yesterday) over (partition by site order by date) as next_arrived_yesterday
from t;
```